# how to fetch data from servlet in file html

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

i know with JSP file i can use scriplet like this:

```java
<% String errorMessage = (String)request.getAttribute("errorMessage"); %>

 <% if (errorMessage != null) { %> 

<h1><%= errorMessage %></h1><br> 

<h1>Login Failed!</h1>

 <% } %>
```

but when i use HTML file how i can fetch data ?

This is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Authentication</title>
<style>
/* Style for the form group */
.form-group {
    display: flex; /* This makes labels and inputs align horizontally */
    margin-bottom: 10px; /* Adds some space between form groups */
    justify-content: center;
}

/* Style for labels */
label {
    margin-top: 5px;
    flex-basis: 100px; /* Set a fixed width for labels (adjust as needed) */
    text-align: center; /* Align labels to the right for better alignment */
}

/* Style for inputs */
input {
    padding: 5px; /* Add some padding for better appearance */
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="authServlet" method="post" style="text-align:center; margin-top:30vh" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>
            Password
        </label>        
        <input type="password" name="pwd">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Connect">   
    </form>
    <h1> Message: ${Users}</h1>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not clear how would you like to fetch data.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused. JSP is compiled into a Servlet, and is principally a **HTML** templating system for Java. As for "fetching" data from a Servlet, the mechanism would typically be to use a web form and GET or POST. Either synchronously with the form submission to a servlet which then either forwards to a JSP or emits HTML directly, **or** by using JavaScript and [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to do so asynchronously ([AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)).